# GeventSocketIOWorker has no attribute 'socket'

Tags: django, socket.io, gunicorn, gevent-socketio

I need to run Django application using gunicorn.
I read documentation, and I think I set up everything like I should, but when I run

```
gunicorn --worker-class socketio.sgunicorn.GeventSocketIOWorker app.wsgi:application
```

I get following error message

```
2013-02-01 18:25:17 [25394] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 25394
2013-02-01 18:25:18 [25394] [ERROR] Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../app-root/data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 485, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File ".../app-root/data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 131, in init_process
    super(GeventWorker, self).init_process()
  File ".../app-root/data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 104, in init_process
    self.run()
  File ".../app-root/data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/sgunicorn.py", line 14, in run
    self.socket.setblocking(1)
AttributeError: 'GeventSocketIOWorker' object has no attribute 'socket'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../app-root/data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 485, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File ".../data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/ggevent.py", line 131, in init_process
    super(GeventWorker, self).init_process()
  File ".../app-root/data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 104, in init_process
    self.run()
  File ".../app-root/data/lib/python2.7/site-packages/socketio/sgunicorn.py", line 14, in run
    self.socket.setblocking(1)
AttributeError: 'GeventSocketIOWorker' object has no attribute 'socket'
2013-02-01 18:25:18 [25394] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 25394)
```

If I run it with django_socketio, everything works fine, I must miss something really important.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with gunicorn>0.17, see [issue #122](https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/pull/122).
For me it's working with the version 0.16.1 of gunicorn.

```
pip install gunicorn==0.16.1
```

Comment: Just in case if anyone is wondering, its October 2014 and this solution still works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that installing gevent-socketio 0.3.6 might fix this without having to revert gunicorn for some cases. I had 0.3.5-rc2 and upgrading fixed this issue for me (NOTE: this was not in django, but it worked.)

`pip install gevent-socketio==0.3.6`

Answer (score 0):

Caused by this change in gunicorn. 
https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/commit/9a83d719b23fe28667a9c76bac25ba66651f8ccf

Previously the sockets used for gevent worker came from gunicorn socket now they wrap gevent cooperative sockets. So reverting to an older version of gunicorn is not good idea. May be disable Flash Policy Server that will disable this check.